# Create a new int list item on click, and output into group box

Tags: c#, list, output, groupbox

I'm very confused on how to create a new list item on the click of a button, and then how to output the list items into a list box once list items have been created.

I have declared the list and named it coin globally:

```
List<int> coin = new List<int>();
```

Then on the click of a button named 'Enter' I am trying to add a new item to the list, which will determine the value of the list item through the for loop, so the value must be higher than the amount of items currently in the list:

```
    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i > coin.Count(); i++)
        {
            coin.Add(i);
        }
    }
```

Then in the list box I am trying to output all of the list items by converting them to a string, and counting the amount of values inside the for loop, like so:

```
    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < coin.Count(); i++)
        {
            string spacesOutput = coin.ToString();
            groupBox1.Text = "/" + spacesOutput;
        }
    }
```

On the click of the enter button nothing happens, and nothing is displayed in the list box so I am a little confused. Thanks.

Comment: Your for loop will never call your Add code, as initially, `coin.Count();` will have a value of 0. Try modifying your for loop logic so that Add will be called even if Count is 0.

Also, in your groupbox, `coin.ToString();` refers to the List itself, rather than the individual 'coin'. You want to use the `i` of your for loop to selct the element, i.e. `coin[i].ToString();`

Comment: @plusheen this should be an answer :)

Comment: Ah whoops. I'll modify and post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first for loop can go 2 ways:
It either does nothing (like right now), because `i` will start at `0`, just like `coin.Count`.
The other option is an endless loop. For this, you have to start counting at `1`: `for (i = 1...`. Neither will do you any good.
I also suppose you want to have the text of your GroupBox to look something like this:

```
/1/2/3/4/5...
```

which you will not accomplish with your code. You convert the List itself to string.
To have the format seen above, I suggest a `StringBuilder` object:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < coin.Count(); i++)
{
    builder.Append("/");
    builder.Append(coin[i].ToString());
}
groupBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop condition will always be set to false. When you click enter, `coin.Count();` is 0, and i is 0. Therefore `coin.Add()` is never called, and nothing happens. Modify your for loop so that `Add();` is called, for example

`for (int i = 0; i <= coin.Count(); i++)
     coin.Add(i);`

This way, if there are no coins in the collection, the for loop will still be run once.

Also, in your groupbox, `coin.ToString();` refers to the `List` itself, rather than the individual 'coin'. You want to use the i of your for loop to selct the element, i.e. `string spacesOutput = coin[i].ToString();`

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to add one coin to the list, the value of which is one more than the number of items in the list.  If so, you need the following:

```
List<int> coin = new List<int>();

private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  coin.Add(coin.Count + 1);
}
```

Then, to output the values of the coins...

```
private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < coin.Count(); i++)
    {
        string spacesOutput = coin[i].ToString();
        groupBox1.Text += "/" + spacesOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are working with very small lists, I would recommend use of a stringbuilder as in Wilsu's answer.